# How to pass variable from kendo grid to template function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, telerik-grid

I have a kendo grid as :

```
    $("#myGrid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: dataSource,
    pageable: false,
    height: 350,
    columns: [
    { field: "Status", title: "Status", width: "130px", template: Getvalue("/#=Status#") },
    ],
    editable: false
});
```

and my function is:

```
    function Getvalue(Status) {
    if (Status == "Detected")
        return "11";
    }
```

The function gets called and it works. but I couldn't pass value of `Status` to function. I tried different things including `/#=Status#` but it doesn't work. any idea?

Comment: i guess that the **Status** variable is recieved from asp.net itself.. maybe you mean <% =Status %> or @Status?

Comment: No, it is form jquery code on dataSource of kendo grid.

Comment: can you please attach some sample records of your data source to the original question?

Comment: What do you mean original question?

Comment: Data comes from external and I could get, change or format it. That is fine. I also could transfer data to any part of code which I want. I only couldn't send data to template function.

Comment: i mean that it would be kind if you put in your code **console.log(dataSource)**,observe it and make a screenshot or copy-paste the result to the original post so we can all enjoy it

Comment: I know my problem comes form how to wrap @Status inside @Getvalue("/#=Status#")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to handle my problem. I found out that my problem comes from this point that I try to send value which hasn't been databounded yet. So there isn't any value to transfer to other function. What I did was defining inline function inside filed and handling all needed changes by function.
So my code now is:

```
$("#LoggerAttachingLogGrid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: mydata,
    pageable: false,
    height: 350,
    columns: [
    { field: "Status", title: "Status", width: "130px", template:
            function (data, type, full, meta) {
            return data.Status == "Detected" ? '<span class="LoggerDetected"><i class="fa fa-bolt"></i> Detected</span>' :
            data.Status == "Configuring" ? '<span class="LoggerConfiguring"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse"></i> Configuring</span>' :
            data.Status == "Configured and attached" ? '<span class="LoggerTick"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Successful</span><br />' :
            data.Status == "Error" ? '<span class="LoggerError"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Error, see alert above</span>' :
            data.Status
            }
    }
    ],

    editable: false
});
```